# React Native: What controls number in red circle on app icon on iPhone screen?

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native, springboard

When I have apps on my iPhone, if I've received a notification of something in that app, a red circle will appear on the top right of the app icon on my iPhone springboard.

If I'm building a React Native app, what controls this number?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use : https://github.com/react-native-push-notification-ios/push-notification-ios

Setting a badge number is only supported on iOS. Badge number is related to number of push notifications for an app, but you can set a custom number based on some other logic like rn-firebase.

`applicationIconBadgeNumber` The number to display as the app's icon badge. The default value of this property is 0, which means that no badge is displayed (optional).

[This tutorial](https://rossbulat.medium.com/react-native-working-with-notification-badges-5e60138b83e8) seems to nail all the portions , but you might want to update the code used in the article.

**Update**: Use [react-native-notification-badge](https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-notification-badge#readme) if you don't want a fully featured notification manager.

Comment: Should I be able to set that number on running a local dev build (with a signed app)?

Comment: @ElleryFamilia yes you can see update in the answer.